# How to extract values of interests between two characters?

Tags: python, html, web-scraping

I'm working on web scraping a web page with the following HTML code:

```
Predecessors &middot; <i class="fa fa-sign-in"></i> / Successors &middot; <i class="fa fa-sign-out"></i>
</dt>

<dd>
    1931 &middot;
    <a class="active" href="../../../aus/party/1253">
                ALP </a> &middot;
    <i class="fa fa-sign-in"> </i> splinter

</dd>

<dd>
    1931 &middot;
    <a class="active" href="../../../aus/party/1905">
                NAT </a> &middot;
    <i class="fa fa-sign-in"> </i> successor

</dd>
```

The code I used to get the above output is as follows:

```
import urllib.request

url_pc = str('http://www.parlgov.org/explore/aus/party/1912/")
fp = urllib.request.urlopen(url_pc)
mybytes = fp.read()

mystr = mybytes.decode("utf8")
fp.close()
#print(mystr)

str1 = mystr[mystr.find('Predecessors'):]

str2 = str1.split("</div>", 1)[0]

str3 = str2.split("<dt> Party (name) changes</dt>", 1)[0]

print(str3)
```

I want to extract everything that is between `<dd>` and `</dd>` in each group make it into a string and then add it to a row of data. Is there a loop I can run or code I can use that will extract all the strings between `<dd>` and `</dd>` in each of the two groups?

Comment: show your code. What module do you use - `lxml`, `BeautifulSoup`, `Selenium`, `Scrapy`, other ?

Comment: do you want all HTML in `<dd></dd>` or only text without HTML's tags?

Comment: Added the code I used.

Comment: Ideally, I'd like to get ```1931 &middot;
              <a class="active"
                 href="../../../aus/party/1253">
                ALP </a>

              &middot;
               <i class="fa fa-sign-in"> </i> 

               splinter  ``` and  ```1931 &middot;
              <a class="active"
                 href="../../../aus/party/1905">
                NAT </a>

              &middot;
               <i class="fa fa-sign-in"> </i> 

               successor  ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `BeautifuSoup` to find all `<dd>` and then get content of every `<dd>` as list. And then you can join elements of list to one string. Some elements can be object which need to be converted to string. You can also use `strip()` to remove some spaces but it may still need so cleaning.

```
text = '''Predecessors &middot; <i class="fa fa-sign-in"></i>
            / Successors &middot; <i class="fa fa-sign-out"></i>
          </dt>

            <dd>
              1931 &middot;
              <a class="active"
                 href="../../../aus/party/1253">
                ALP </a>

              &middot;
               <i class="fa fa-sign-in"> </i> 

               splinter 



            </dd>

            <dd>
              1931 &middot;
              <a class="active"
                 href="../../../aus/party/1905">
                NAT </a>

              &middot;
               <i class="fa fa-sign-in"> </i> 

               successor 



            </dd>'''

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS

soup = BS(text, 'html.parser')

for item in soup.find_all('dd'):
    print(''.join(str(x).strip() for x in item.contents))
```

Result

```
1931 ·<a class="active" href="../../../aus/party/1253">
                ALP </a>·<i class="fa fa-sign-in"> </i>splinter
1931 ·<a class="active" href="../../../aus/party/1905">
                NAT </a>·<i class="fa fa-sign-in"> </i>successor
```

---

**EDIT:**

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS

soup = BS(text, 'html.parser')

all_rows = []

for item in soup.find_all('dd'):
    #print(''.join(str(x).strip() for x in item.contents))
    row = (item.contents[0].strip()[:-2], item.find('a').get_text().strip(), item.contents[4].strip(), item.find('a').get('href')[-4:])
    row = ', '.join(row)
    print(row)
    all_rows.append(row)

text = ' | '.join(all_rows)
print(text)
```

Result:

```
1931, ALP, splinter, 1253
1931, NAT, successor, 1905
1931, ALP, splinter, 1253 | 1931, NAT, successor, 1905
```

Comment: Perfect! The ultimate goal is to get it into the following format ```1931, ALP, splinter, 1253 |
1931, NAT, successor, 1905```. This was a huge step in that direction! Thank you again.

Comment: `item.contents` gives list with strings `"1931 ·"` and `"splinter"`. `item.find('a').get('href')` gives string `"../../../aus/party/1253"` which you have to slice `[-4:]` or `split('/')`. `item.find('a').get_text()` gives `ALP`- so you have all elements to create your string.

Comment: see new code in answer. It gives string `1931, ALP, splinter, 1253 | 1931, NAT, successor, 1905`